# regex column selection inside pd.melt function

Tags: pandas, pandas-melt

I have a very wide df with about 100 columns, within which there are several 'XYZ_rating' columns that I want to pivot longer.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({

    'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],

    'first_rating': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],

    'second_rating': [2.8, 2.9, 2.2, 2, 1.8, 1.9, 2.2, 2.3, 2.1],

    'third_rating': [3.4, 3.8, 2.9, 3.2, 2.8, 2.4, 3.3, 3.4, 2.9],

})
```

The df in question has about 100 other columns that I do not want to transform from wide to long. I also want to remove the '_rating' suffix from the the category string.

The solution I came up with didn't work and is roughly translated from my R background.

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=str.contains('[^rating]'), value_vars=re.contains(`rating`), var_name='category', value_name='value')
```

Desired output df would look like:

| id | category | rating | 100 other columns... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first | 1 | ... |
| 1 | second | 2.8 | ... |
| 1 | third | 3.4 | ... |
| ... |  |  |  |

Comment: Have a look at `pd.wide_to_long` or pyjanitor `pivot_longer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to reshape with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using `names_sep` to split into new columns:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df
.pivot_longer(
    # you could pass a regex here : 
    # re.compile(".+rating")
    column_names = "*rating", # uses the shell glob syntax
    names_to = ("category", ".value"), 
    names_sep = "_")
)
    id category  rating
0    1    first     1.0
1    1    first     2.0
2    1    first     3.0
3    2    first     1.0
4    2    first     2.0
5    2    first     3.0
6    3    first     1.0
7    3    first     2.0
8    3    first     3.0
9    1   second     2.8
10   1   second     2.9
11   1   second     2.2
12   2   second     2.0
13   2   second     1.8
14   2   second     1.9
15   3   second     2.2
16   3   second     2.3
17   3   second     2.1
18   1    third     3.4
19   1    third     3.8
20   1    third     2.9
21   2    third     3.2
22   2    third     2.8
23   2    third     2.4
24   3    third     3.3
25   3    third     3.4
26   3    third     2.9
```

Comment: Thank you. I use janitor a lot in R and this reads well to me.